# CSV Import RSpec error in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, methods, rspec

I am working on an assignment in Ruby.. I had to write RSPEC tests for a method that removes an entry from my address_book app.. and also had to write a test and a method for importing 5 entries from a CSV. In my remove_entry method when I run the Specs it says that I have an undefined method of delete. I have already asked a couple fellow ruby devs and they could not figure it out at first glance. The next error is that when I run the tests for my CSV imports.. The data is not being imported in the proper order. I have spent several hours walking through my code over and over and researching in attempts to fix this.. I am at my wits end.. Any help would be appreciated!

address_book.rb

```
require_relative 'entry'
require "csv"
class AddressBook
   attr_accessor :entries

   def initialize
     @entries = []
   end


   def add_entry(name,phone_number,email)
     index = 0
     @entries.each do |entry|
       if name < entry.name
         break
       end
       index += 1
     end
     @entries.insert(index, Entry.new(name, phone_number, email))
   end

   def import_from_csv(file_name)
     csv_text = File.read(file_name)
     csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, headers: true, skip_blanks: true)

     csv.each do |row|
       row_hash = row.to_hash
       add_entry(row_hash["name"], row_hash["phone_number"], row_hash["email"])
       #can you clarify what the above is doing
       #is the format of row_hash["name"] because it is iterating over a hash or because it is an array?
     end
   end

   def remove_entry(name,phone_number,email)
     @entries.each do |entry|
       if (name == entry.name) && (email ==  entry.email) && (phone_number = entry.phone_number)
         entry.delete #this line returns an error in my RSPEC test
       else
         p "Entry does not exist \n Please try again."
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

address_book_spec.rb

```
require_relative "../models/address_book"

RSpec.describe AddressBook do
  let(:book) {AddressBook.new} # => lets us use the book variable in every test

  describe "attributes" do
    it "should respond to entries" do
     # book = AddressBook.new # => Replaced by line 4
     expect(book).to respond_to(:entries)
   end

   it "should initialize entries as an array" do
     # book = AddressBook.new # => Replaced by line 4
     expect(book.entries).to be_a(Array)
   end

   it "should initialize entries as an empty array" do
     # book = AddressBook.new # => Replaced by line 4
     expect(book.entries.size).to eq(0)
   end
  end
  describe "#add_entry" do
    it "adds only a single entry to the Address Book" do
      # book = AddressBook.new # => Replaced by line 4
      book.add_entry('Ada Lovelace', '010.012.1815', 'augusta.king@lovelace.com')
      expect(book.entries.size).to eq(1)
    end
    it "adds the correct information to entries" do
      # book = AddressBook.new # => Replaced by line 4
      book.add_entry('Ada Lovelace', '010.012.1815', 'augusta.king@lovelace.com')
      new_entry = book.entries[0]

      expect(new_entry.name).to eq('Ada Lovelace')
      expect(new_entry.phone_number).to eq('010.012.1815')
      expect(new_entry.email).to eq('augusta.king@lovelace.com')
    end
  end
  # added remove entry test
  describe "#remove_entry" do
    it "should remove a single entry" do
      # book = AddressBook.new # => Replaced by line 4
      book.add_entry('Austin Thesing', '800.445.8833','austin@thesing.xyz')
      expect(book.entries.size).to eq(1)

      book.remove_entry('Austin Thesing', '800.445.8833','austin@thesing.xyz')
      expect(book.entries.size).to eq(0)
    end
  end
  def check_entry(entry,expected_name,expected_phone_number, expected_email)
    expect(entry.name).to eql(expected_name)
    expect(entry.phone_number).to eql(expected_phone_number)
    expect(entry.email).to eql(expected_email)
  end
  describe "#import_from_csv" do
    it "import an entry from a CSV file" do
      book.import_from_csv("entries.csv")
      book_size = book.entries.size

      expect(book_size).to eq 5 #checks the size of the book
    end
    it "adds the first entry" do
      book.import_from_csv("entries.csv")
      entry_one = book.entries[0]
      check_entry(entry_one,"Mark Griffo","123456789","mark@bloc.com")
    end
    it "adds the second entry" do
      book.import_from_csv("entries.csv")
      entry_two = book.entries[1]
      check_entry(entry_two,"Natalie Griffo","123456789","natalie@bloc.com")
    end
    it "adds the third entry" do
      book.import_from_csv("entries.csv")
      entry_three = book.entries[2]
      check_entry(entry_three, "Steve Thesing", "8583878899", "steve@steve.com")
    end
    it "adds the fourth entry" do
      book.import_from_csv("entries.csv")
      entry_four = book.entries[3]
      check_entry(entry_four, "Haidee Thesing", "8584458833", "h@thesing.com")
    end
    it "adds the fifth entry" do
      book.import_from_csv("entries.csv")
      entry_five = book.entries[4]
      check_entry(entry_five, "Olivia Meers", "0987654321", "olivia@meers.com")
    end
  end
end
```

Terminal Output/Spec Failures

```
Austins-MacBook-Pro:address-bloc austinthesing$ rspec spec/address_book_spec.rb 
.....F.FFFFF

Failures:

  1) AddressBook#remove_entry should remove a single entry
     Failure/Error: book.remove_entry('Austin Thesing', '800.445.8833','austin@thesing.xyz')
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `delete' for #<Entry:0x007f8e8c1dea08>
     # ./models/address_book.rb:37:in `block in remove_entry'
     # ./models/address_book.rb:35:in `each'
     # ./models/address_book.rb:35:in `remove_entry'
     # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:45:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) AddressBook#import_from_csv adds the first entry
     Failure/Error: expect(entry.name).to eql(expected_name)

       expected: "Mark Griffo"
            got: "Haidee Thesing"

       (compared using eql?)
     # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:50:in `check_entry'
     # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:64:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) AddressBook#import_from_csv adds the second entry
     Failure/Error: expect(entry.name).to eql(expected_name)

       expected: "Natalie Griffo"
            got: "Mark Griffo"

       (compared using eql?)
     # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:50:in `check_entry'
     # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:69:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) AddressBook#import_from_csv adds the third entry
     Failure/Error: expect(entry.name).to eql(expected_name)

       expected: "Steve Thesing"
            got: "Natalie Griffo"

       (compared using eql?)
     # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:50:in `check_entry'
     # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:74:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) AddressBook#import_from_csv adds the fourth entry
     Failure/Error: expect(entry.name).to eql(expected_name)

       expected: "Haidee Thesing"
            got: "Olivia Meers"

       (compared using eql?)
     # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:50:in `check_entry'
     # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:79:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) AddressBook#import_from_csv adds the fifth entry
     Failure/Error: expect(entry.name).to eql(expected_name)

       expected: "Olivia Meers"
            got: "Steve Thesing"

       (compared using eql?)
     # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:50:in `check_entry'
     # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:84:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.0176 seconds (files took 0.08714 seconds to load)
12 examples, 6 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:40 # AddressBook#remove_entry should remove a single entry
rspec ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:61 # AddressBook#import_from_csv adds the first entry
rspec ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:66 # AddressBook#import_from_csv adds the second entry
rspec ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:71 # AddressBook#import_from_csv adds the third entry
rspec ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:76 # AddressBook#import_from_csv adds the fourth entry
rspec ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:81 # AddressBook#import_from_csv adds the fifth entry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First test is failing because the delete method is being used incorrectly:

```
entry.delete #this line returns an error in my RSPEC test
```

needs to be

```
@entries.delete(entry)
```

Entries are being inserted in a scrambled fashion because you are using break where you probably want

```
next
```

(I suppose that loop is supposed to insert in alphabetical order.)

break command terminates the full each block, so no more iterations are executed if there is one name of higher alphabetical order, next just skips to the next iteration.

That should be it